# How to add Limit to Date_Time in SQLite for Android

Tags: sqlite, android-activity, android-sqlite

The following line is used for `query` in Android,  where orderBy is the parameter

```
String orderBy = Helper.COLUMN_DATE_TIME +" DESC";
```

This arranges the table rows in descending order of time. The value of date_time is in the format %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S

I would like to introduce `LIMIT` in the above statement (as in some instances I am only in need of `%Y-%m-%d`). How can this be done? I mean I am limited by my knowledge and try. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: The description is unclear. Do you want to sort only by the date, and have the rows of the same day sorted randomly?

Comment: @CL. Yes, I want to sort only by date (%Y-%m-%d) and not by date along with time  (%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S)

Comment: And how should the rows in the same day be sorted?

Comment: Initially I had a separate column for date and time. However, I am trying to use a single column for date and time. Hence trying to make use of limit function to order the data by date alone

Comment: This does not answer my question.

Comment: Sorry, my last statement was just a continuation to my previous one. To answer your question, yes. rows will be sorted by date but randomly. However, I am thinking what if orderby is ASC or DESC and sorting the rows by DATE can be performed using WHERE clause. Is it possible?

Comment: WHERE does not sort.

Answer (score 0):

To extract the date part of a timestamp, use the [date() function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html):

```java
String orderBy = "date("+Helper.COLUMN_DATE_TIME+") DESC";
```